# How can we make multiple Boiler plate for c++ in Visusal Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, templates, vscode-snippets

i have made a boiler plate for cpp like

```
{
  // Place your snippets for cpp here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a prefix, body and
  // description. The prefix is what is used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are:
  // $1, $2 for tab stops, $0 for the final cursor position, and ${1:label}, ${2:another} for placeholders. Placeholders with the
  // same ids are connected.
  // Example:
  "template": {
    "prefix": "template",
    "body": [
      "#include <bits/stdc++.h>",
      "using namespace std;",
      "int main()",
      "{",
      " $1",
      "return 0;",
      "}"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
  }
}
```

but i want to make more snippets like for gcd, function, modulus and many more . When ever i clicked on user snippet cpp then this appear. How can i make more snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code that I figured out after much experimentation,

```
{
// Place your snippets for cpp here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a prefix, body and 
// description. The prefix is what is used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are:
// $1, $2 for tab stops, $0 for the final cursor position, and ${1:label}, ${2:another} for placeholders. Placeholders with the 
// same ids are connected.
// Example:
// "Print to console": {
//  "prefix": "log",
//  "body": [
//      "console.log('$1');",
//      "$2"
//  ],
//  "description": "Log output to console"
// }
"cpp snippets":
{
    "prefix" : "cpp boilerplate",
               "body" : [
                   "#include<iostream>",
                   "using namespace std;",
                   "int main()",
                   "{",
                   "    $0",
                   "    return 0;",
                   "}"

               ],
                        "description" : "to produce the main snippet for cpp"
},

"ccsnippets":{
    "prefix" : "ccc boilerplate",
                "body" : [
                    "#include<iostream>",
                    "using namespace std;",
                    "int main()",
                    "{",
                    "ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);"
                    "   $0",
                    "   return 0;",
                    "}"
                ],
                        "description" : "snippet for competetive coding"
}
```

}

Basically, you have to put a comma ',' outside of the bracket of the first snippet, create a new title(in my case "ccsnippets":), place a curly bracket '{', and put in your code with new prefix and body.

Hope this helps!!